# specify root volume size for ec2 instance in cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudformation

Inherited an amazon hosted infrastructure consisting of a load balancer, a DB server, and several webservers inside an autoscaling group; with deployment coordinated by CloudFormation.

Problem is, the spun webservers have a puny root volume (8gb), and sometimes during the webserver lifetime the disk gets filled with logs and temporary files and some services stop working.

I found the part where the machine definition is declared (I think):

```
...
"Properties": {
            "ImageId": {
                "Fn::FindInMap": [
                    "AWSRegionArch2AMI",
                    {
                        "Ref": "AWS::Region"
                    },
                    {
                        "Fn::FindInMap": [
                            "AWSInstanceType2Arch",
                            {
                                "Ref": "InstanceType"
                            },
                            "Arch"
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            "InstanceType": {
                "Ref": "InstanceType"
            },
            "SecurityGroups": [
                {
                    "Ref": "WebServerSecurityGroup"
                }
            ],
            "KeyName": {
                "Ref": "KeyName"
            },
            "UserData": {
                "Fn::Base64": {
                    "Fn::Join": [
...
```

Instance type is ultimatetly defined somewhere else:

```
"InstanceType": {
  "Description": "WebServer EC2 instance type",
  "Type": "String",
  "Default": "c4.xlarge",
  "AllowedValues": [
    "t1.micro",
    "t2.nano",
     # ... more allowed values
    "cg1.4xlarge"
  ],
  "ConstraintDescription": "must be a valid EC2 instance type."
},
```

But I have no clue how to declare the root volume size, nor if it possible at all; and I can't see anywhere an ebs volume being declared.

This is a linux machine, and the root device is /dev/xvda1

```
[ec2-user@ip- /]$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1      7.8G  1.6G  6.2G  21% /
devtmpfs        3.7G   60K  3.7G   1% /dev
tmpfs           3.7G     0  3.7G   0% /dev/shm
```

Tried the [solution](https://serverfault.com/a/862594/242978) suggested by @Jason (although replacing `sda1` with `xvda1`) but CloudFormation wont spin up any new machines after doing that.

I can see that the launch configuration for the machine is updated accordingly after I upload the new template with these changes:
[image: screenshot showing disk size of 20gb in AWS console]

But new machines won't spin up automatically any more. :(

Comment: Also posted before in SO: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19146271/1736679

Answer (score 8):

I had been stuck for days to change root-disk size using Cloudformation, , this is how it works for me..

If you use `/dev/xvda1` the instance will fail, the correct way is to use `/dev/xvda`.

Using YAML format:

```
BlockDeviceMappings:
- DeviceName: "/dev/xvda"
   Ebs:
      VolumeSize: 15
```

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39768904/1736679

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html, specifically the section about 'Block Device Mappings'.  You will follow that down to a EBS device definition, which looks like:

```
{
   "DeleteOnTermination" : Boolean,
   "Encrypted" : Boolean,
   "Iops" : Number,
   "SnapshotId" : String,
   "VolumeSize" : String,
   "VolumeType" : String
}
```

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=127767 also describes this:

```
"MyEC2Instance" : {
  "Type" : "AWS::EC2::Instance",
  "Properties" : {
  ............
  .....
  ..
      "BlockDeviceMappings" : [
         {
           "DeviceName" : "/dev/sda1",
              "Ebs" : {
                 "VolumeSize" : "20"
               }
         }
      ],

      "UserData" : {"Fn::Base64" : {"Fn::Join" : ["", [
         "#!/bin/bash\n",
          "/sbin/resize2fs /dev/sda1\n"
       ]]}},
  }
}
```

Alternatively you could rebuild the AMIs to have this larger size intrinsically.

Comment: Ok... I guess that if my root device is `/dev/xvda1`, that's the one I should refer to in DeviceName, right? And the `BlockDeviceMappings` section is _inside_ the properties section, at the same level than `UserData', right? And the call to resize2fs doesn't take any other parameters besides the device to resize?

Comment: This looks nice in theory, but when I apply it cloudformation stops spinning up my machines.

Comment: @yivi what error does it give?

Comment: None that I can find. But that could be simply me not finding the error. The autoscaling group sits silently and doesn't launch any new machines. As soon as I remove this block and re-update the template, everything goes back to normal.

Comment: Probably need to make sure the json is valid. Did you run it through a validator ([example](https://jsoneditoronline.org/))? If you copy paste the code above it has the classic trailing comma invalid json after "UserData"